# Select loop react js with array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have an array of objects

```
let arr= [0: {received: "Return Received", approved: "Approved", rejected: "Rejected"} 1: {authorized: "Authorized", received: "Return Received"}}
```

I want to push data into `<option></options>`

where first set should make an option set like fist set create and option and second next option when executing in loop

ex :

```
<Select><option key="received" >Return Received</options<option key="approved">Approved</options><option key="rejected">Rejected</options><Select>

<Select><option key="authorized" >Authorized</options><option key="received">ReturnReceived</options><Select>
```

I tried the below code but im getting all result in single option

```
const listItems = Object.entries(arr).map(([key, value]) => (
        console.log(Object.keys(arr[0]).length),
        Object.entries(value).map(([name, data]) => (
            <option key={name}>{name}</option>
        ) 
        )
    )
    );
```

`<Select native={true}>{listItems}<Select>`

Comment: Is it safe to assume your first `arr` code should be `let arr = { ...` instead of `let arr = [ ...`?

Comment: I am pushing the data from another object. something like this, let arr = [ ] ; arr.push(obj);

Comment: `(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {received: "Return Received", approved: "Approved", rejected: "Rejected"}
1: {authorized: "Authorized", received: "Return Received"}
length: 2  `     This is how it shows in console.log

Comment: Can you add a pen of some sort? stackblitz / codepen, etc.?

Comment: I don't know how to add it up. its just array of objects and need to loop to select option. each object set should create a new select @alexunder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be creating one `<select>` per key, but you're only creating one in total.  Try something like this:

```
  const obj = {
    0: {
      received: "Return Received",
      approved: "Approved",
      rejected: "Rejected"
    },
    1: {
      authorized: "Authorized",
      received: "Return Received"
    }
  };

  const listItems = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => (
    <select key={key}>
      {Object.entries(value).map(([name, data]) => (
        <option key={name}>{name}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  ));
```

Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-feather-emizf

It's also a little weird that you're calling `arr` an array and you say you're `push`ing data into it, but then using `Object.entries` and what seems like object syntax for it.  Anyway, I assumed it's an object above.  Just in case you're stuck on the array aspect, I added an array structure too:

```
  const arr = [
    {
      received: "Return Received",
      approved: "Approved",
      rejected: "Rejected"
    },
    {
      authorized: "Authorized",
      received: "Return Received"
    }
  ];

  const arrList = arr.map((value, index) => (
    <select key={index}>
      {Object.entries(value).map(([name, data]) => (
        <option key={name}>{name}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  ));
```

Comment: Im getting this error : Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {arrList}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. @ChrisFarmer

Comment: I linked to a functional codesandbox. If you're getting an error trying to map that to your own stuff, maybe include some code that's failing.

Comment: Can i update the sandbox ? so you can check where is it going wrong. i tried multiple ways but giving same issue @Chris

Comment: File -> Fork Sandbox

Comment: It worked !! Actually some extra data was loading as result it was failing. Thanks a lot @Chris